# SAPUI5 application is not updated immediately from SAP NetWeaver

Tags: sapui5, netweaver

I am developing an SAPUI5 application for our company. The application is served from our SAP NetWeaver system.

As the application is still under development and new features have to be tested, we noticed that the users do not get the updated version of the app immediately. So I often get emails on why they don't see the changes and I always have to tell to refresh the page.

Is there a way to make sure the most current version of the application is being loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey i would say this is all about Cache Management in SAP Fiori/SAPUI5:

#### Cache Management in SAP Fiori

There are different Layers that handle caching:

- The browser itself [HTTP caching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching)
- Your frontend server (ICM) - If you take a look at transaction `SMICM` you can see for example that views/controllers of an UI5 Application are getting stored with an validity period
- Backend Server (only Metadata Caching of your services/service definition)

[Good blog post about Cache Management in SAP Fiori](https://blogs.sap.com/2015/06/16/sap-fiori-cache-management/)

#### Solutions:

- When deploying your UI5 App via WEBIDE the *app_index* get's calculated. Sometimes this fails. So inbefore saying *Test now!* run the report [`/UI5/APP_INDEX_CALCULATE`](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/0002449635) for your specific SAPUI5 application in your frontend server.
- If your OData service changed run the transaction `/IWFND/CACHE_CLEANUP` in your frontend server and the transaction `/IWBEP/CACHE_CLEANUP` in the backend server.
- For myself in developement and quality  management system i sometimes run the report [`/UI2/INVALIDATE_CLIENT_CACHES`](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_nw75/7.5.5/en-US/9c/214a9eb00b4d7daf2d1ff36d446c1f/content.htm?no_cache=true) if changed translations `SE63` doesn't show up.

---

So in developement & quality management system just run `/UI5/APP_INDEX_CALCULATE` and `/UI2/INVALIDATE_CLIENT_CACHES` and you should be good to go.

In Production take care, caching is all about performance, so if you clear all caches and your company has like 500 users opening Fiori Launchpad at 08:00 am things can get messy.